# How to get the ID of an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, ide

I use Arduino Pro Mini. As I know, every MCU has a number. Different MCU has different number.  How to get it ?

Comment: You should also know that not everything you know is so.

Comment: Do you mean, every (single) **chip** has a unique number? Or does every **type** of chip have a signature?

Comment: @NickGammon   I mean every single chip has a unique number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino Pro mini is based on Atmega328 which does not have a unique ID. It has only `device signature` which you can read if you turn on `Show verbose output during upload` in Arduino IDE's **File** > **Preferences**.

Comment: But as I know , every Microchip  have a unique number.

Comment: Really? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

Could you be confusing the term micro-chip (often applied to any tiny, programmable electronic device) with the manufacturer named "Microchip" (who make the PIC series of micro-controllers, among many other products)? Microchip (the company) does make a line of products that have individually unique IDs. Most manufacturers do not provide unique IDs in their micro-controller devices, and AVR's Atmega 328 series devices do not have unique ID's.

Comment: Thanks, I understand you. Because I seemly remeber STM32 and 51 has unique ID, so I think 328 has too.